# What does DRAFT mean in YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I sometimes see `DRAFT` in the videos I upload on YouTube:
[image]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exact question was answered in [a post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/NdFAHR5mm9M) by a user named "ytKeane" who is a Google employee:

> It means that your video isn't live yet. With the changes we made to the uploader this week, if you have a public video that's been uploaded, you need to "Publish" it before it goes live to your subscribers. Public videos that haven't been published are in "draft". In Video Manager there should be a big blue Publish button next to videos that have not been published.

Comment: Sounds like they tried to imitate the draft term in Gmail.